# Unable to delete Listview item

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a Listview and a button like this

[image]

Below is the code I have used for deletion of Data from Listview

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    If lvNotesList.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Dim Result = MsgBox("Are sure you want to Delete the Selected Item ?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo + vbQuestion)
        If Result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Dim ID As String = lvNotesList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text

            Try
                Dim sqlConnection As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
                Dim sqlCommand As New SQLiteCommand("", sqlConnection)
                Dim sqlPath As String = "Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Database\SimpleDB.db3"
                Dim sqlQuery As String = "DELETE FROM Notes WHERE NoteID = " & ID
                sqlConnection.ConnectionString = sqlPath
                sqlConnection.Open()
                sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                sqlConnection.Close()
                MsgBox("Operation Successfull", vbInformation)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error: Operation Unsuccessfull." & Chr(13) & "Sumamry:" & ex.Message, vbExclamation)
            End Try

        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Select an Item First", vbExclamation)
    End If
End Sub
```

For some Reason it produces an Error like this

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MsgBox` causes the ListView to lose focus which in turn clears the selection. You'll have to set [`HideSelection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection.aspx) property of your ListView to `false`.

EDIT:

Try this

```
If lvNotesList.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Dim ID As String = lvNotesList.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
        Dim Result = MsgBox("Are sure you want to Delete the Selected Item ?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo + vbQuestion)
        If Result = DialogResult.Yes Then
```

Comment: Yes it works perfect when I remove the msgbox. But then how can I warn the user ?

Comment: set HideSelection to false for your listview from the designer.